# How can I perform zandatsu on a Gekko?

Tags: metal-gear-rising-revengeance

What is a sure (or good) way to get a [zandatsu](http://metalgear.wikia.com/wiki/Zandatsu) on a [gekko](http://metalgear.wikia.com/wiki/Gekko)?  I am playing on a PS3 but a XBoX solution would be as well.

Comment: Your are playing on what platform?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add to Celta's answer, Gekko's have a charge attack which they use when you are at a distance. If you parry this attack it will lead to a quick time event (QTE), which will position Raiden for an easy Zandatsu.

The gekko also has a stomp attack, if it misses this attack the Gekko's leg will be stuck on the ground. If you're within range you can initiate a QTE which will cause the Gekko to turn blue (i.e. vulnerable to Zandatsu).

Answer (score 2):

I found in a forum information on [What are the ways to destroy Gekkos?](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/960699-metal-gear-rising-revengeance/65316591)

**Stealth Kill:**

> Circle (When Close) > He stabs the Head, cuts the legs, then flips
>   through the legs:
>
> Then you can do Blade Mode for 2 Vertical Slashes (for Zandatsu) +
>   Anything Else > Circle to finish Zandatsu Animation
>
> (I recently learned once you expose the Fuel Cell in Cyborgs/UGs you
>   can cut them any way you want after that and STILL get a Zandatsu so
>   once the cell is exposed you can take your time cutting other parts a
>   bit more...though in the demo this may cause the game to crash if you
>   cut them up too much and immediately Ninja Run to the next enemy
>   target, I guess you can't accidently cut up your Fuel Cells once you
>   exposed them for Zandatsu).

**Zandatsu Finisher:**

> I guess if you somehow manage to "stun" a Gekko through parry or
>   otherwise, you can press "Triangle"+"Circle" to begin a Blade Mode
>   combo and go for a Zandatsu.